# Required initializers for a subclass of UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, subclassing

I've been attempting to follow a tutorial about creating a container view controller. It's in Objective-C. I want to convert it to Swift. I've found some of the same questions here, but I didn't get too much out of them.

Here's the code.

```
import UIKit

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController { // Class "ContainerViewController" has no initializers - That I know why.

    // 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by a subclass of UIViewController

    var currentDetailViewController: UIViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

I've tried doing what both errors say, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is: If you declare any stored properties *without* initial value, you must implement your own initializer to initialize them. see [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_307).

Like this:

```
var currentDetailViewController: UIViewController

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    currentDetailViewController = UIViewController()
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

convenience override init() {
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    currentDetailViewController = UIViewController()
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)
}
```

But, I think this is **not** what you want.

The correct solution depends on where you initialize `currentDetailViewController`.

If you always initialize it within `viewDidLoad`, then you can declare it as an ["Implicitly Unwrapped Optional"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_504)

```
var currentDetailViewController: UIViewController!

override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.currentDetailViewController = DetailViewController()
}
```

otherwise, If `currentDetailViewController` can be `nil`, you should declare it as an ["Optional"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496)

```
var currentDetailViewController: UIViewController?
```